# Go Channels: How to make this non-blocking?

Tags: go, channel

I have a script which is selecting some data from a database and sending this to a channel to be processed by multiple goroutines, with the results then sent back to the main thread to be updated on the database.

However, it is hanging (probably blocking) on sending the data to first channel.

The channels are created globally with:

```
var chin = make(chan in)
var chout = make(chan out)
```

`in` and `out` are both `structs`

First the goroutines are started:

```
for i:=0; i<5; i++ {
     go worker()
}
```

The code to load the channels is then:

```
        if verbose {
            fmt.Println(`Getting nextbatch2 and sending to workers`)
        }

        rows, err = nextbatch2.Query()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        var numtodo int
        for rows.Next() {
            err = rows.Scan(&id, &data)
            if err != nil {
                rows.Close()
                panic(err)
            }

            // Start
            var vin in
            vin.id = id
            vin.data = data
            chin <- vin
            numtodo++
        }
        rows.Close()
```

Then immediately after this:

```
        if verbose {
            fmt.Println(`Processing out channel from workers`)
        }

        for res := range chout {
            update5.Exec(res.data, res.id)
            if numtodo--; numtodo == 0 {
                break
            }
        }
```

And in the background are multiple `worker()` goroutines running:

```
func worker() {
      for res := range chin {
            var v out
            v.id = res.id
            v.data = process(res.data)
            chout <- v
      }
}
```

This code hangs after printing `Getting nextbatch2 and sending to workers`. It never gets to `Processing out channel from workers`. So it's hanging somewhere inside the `rows.Next()` loop, for which I can't figure out the reason as the `chin` channel should be non-blocking - even if the `worker()` goroutines were not processing it should still at least finish that loop.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

By adding on `fmt.Println(" on", numtodo)` at the end of the `rows.Next()` loop I can see that it blocks after 5, which I don't understand as it should be non-blocking, right?

**EDIT 2:**

By changing the channels to `make(chan in/out, 100)` it now will block after 105.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Receivers always block until there is data to receive. If the channel is unbuffered, the sender blocks until the receiver has received the value.

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels

So you can rewrite your consumer-code to something like:

```
go func(){
    for res := range chout {
        update5.Exec(res.data, res.id)
    }
}()
```

Also you need to `close(chin)` and `close(chout)` for proper usage of `range` statement.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, it blocks before that. The problem is not the receiver blocking, the receiver is meant to block. The problem is the `chin` channel blocking. Also they do not need to be closed as the whole thing is looped infinitely, although you don't see that code here.

Comment: Your `worker()` can't send to `chout` as no goroutine reads `chout` yet.

Comment: Does it not just collect in a queue?

Comment: No. `make(chan in)` creates unbuffered (synchronous) channel.

Comment: OK, I see... so is there not a way to make channels accept any number of records rather than block after they reach a particular size?

Comment: OK, I understand now. You're right. I didn't realize channels worked like that.

Comment: You get it. Common way is to run producers and consumers as separate goroutines leaving to main goroutine setup and correct finish.

Comment: @Alasdair, if you really want an unlimited buffer/queue between a channel writer and reader you can do that by using two channels with a relatively straight forward goroutine queuing in the middle.

Comment: This is good, but be careful with large buffers - they might hide a deadlock and then you'd get unexpected behaviour in some different way. It often helps to get everything working first with zero buffering (which entails designing out deadlocks), then add buffering as an optimisation step.